# Есть ли возможность сортировки части столбца в БД sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3

Есть БД с id пользователя и суммой его кошелька. Можно ли отсортировать 10 самых богатых юзеров?
Что-то на подобии
SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY money DESC;
С указанием количества 10 самых богатых.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте LIMIT:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY money DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Больше примеров и подробностей здесь: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-limit/